# PHP - MySQL Transaction execution error

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

```
    $tran = "START TRANSACTION;";  

    $tran_res = mysql_query($tran);  

    $qry_1 = "INSERT INTO docList (doc_ip , doc_country , doc_ref) VALUES ('$ip' , '$country' , '$http_ref');";  
    $res_1 = mysql_query($qry_1);  
    if(!$res_1)
        die ("qry1 fail " . mysql_error() );  

    $ins_id = mysql_insert_id();  
    if(!$ins_id) 
        die ("ins id fail " . mysql_error() );  
    echo "<b>$ins_id</b>";  

    $qry_2 = "INSERT INTO docContent (doc_id , cont_date , cont_title , cont_aim , cont_obj , cont_theory , cont_sw , cont_code) VALUES ('$ins_id' , '$dt' , '$title' , '$aim' , '$obj' , '$th' , '$sw' , '$code');"; 

    $res_2 = mysql_query($qry_2);  
    if(!$res_2)
        die("qry2 fail " . mysql_error() );  `
```

The execution of above is returning the following error:

`2 qry fail`   `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'login'); if($query->num_rows()>0) return $query->result_array(); } ' at line 1`

In effect the execution of `$qry_2` is failing, but I am perplexed by the error it is showing (there is no such code on line 1 as mentioned in the error note). Moreover, the query (`$qry_2`) executes properly in the MySql console.

Comment: Looks like you're not sanitizing your variables.

Comment: @Juhana You are right! It working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't posted the real query as received by the MySQL server, but I'd dare say you haven't used [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to inject your data into your SQL.

*(Are you trying to insert PHP code in the database?)*

Comment: Yes the Code in the query can be from any language and of course it has been cured after 'sanitization' by use of mysql_escape_*

Answer (score 2):

Output the contents of `$qry_2` to see the actual SQL statement be executed. Most likely you've got SQL injection vulnerabilities, and one of the variables you're inserting contains at least `'` somewhere, causing the syntax error.

e.g. if you have

```
$var = "O'Reilly";
$sql = "INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('$var')";
```

you'll end up with

```
INSERT INTO names (name) VALUES ('O'Reilly');
```

which will be interpreted as:

```
'O' - string containing the letter "O"
Reilly - a field named "Reilly", with no operator between this "field" and the "O" previous
'); - a weird unterminated string, also with no operator between this and the previous field.
```

To get around this, you **MUST** pass your variables through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, which will prevent such errors from occuring. It'll turn `O'Reilly` into `O\'Reilly`, which is "safe" to use in your query.